# How to export maps with PNG images with transparent background to PDF?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, export, pdf

On the Data View in ArcGIS 10, I have some polygons and one PNG image (wind rose) with transparent background.

When I export what is showing on the screen to PNG, the compass appears in the output. When exporting the same to PDF, it doesn't.

Is there a way to get everything exported to a PDF?

Comment: Do you have a compass in the layout view?

Comment: Try *printing* to pdf, rather than exporting. Assuming you have a PDF 'printer'.

Comment: @ChrisW Thanks for the printing idea, but it creates the same problem described above -- an image with a lot more map that I need -- and another one: the compass's background becomes white.

Comment: When marking this question as duplicate, did you guys factor in the fact that the person in the other question was trying to export from layout view and not from data view? Does it not make a difference in ArcMap?

Comment: @gyoung1986 I do. I knew this before but I wanted to avoid the hassle the layout view creates. The layout view shows slightly more map than what you can see when you zoom in an area in the data view. I need several screenshots of smaller areas of the same map, so going back and forth from data to layout view several times until I find the perfect zoom to export is a small hassle. But because ArcMap can't export my PNG properly, I suppose the most sensible thing to do is to accept the small hassle and use the built-in compass in layout view, as you suggest.

Comment: ps: the answer in the other question didn't work for me. ArcMap says "No graphics that can be converted to features have been found." when I try to convert my PNG to a feature.

Comment: I'm sure that you know this, but you can change the zoom of the data view from the layout view. Its the map scale box on the standard toolbar. Or you can use the tools toolbar magnifying glass to do the same without switching between views. You may also try converting the png to a jpeg.

Comment: No, the issue isn't layout/data view, it's Esri's pdf driver/export routine and the way they handle transparency in general. I'm not sure what you mean by "a lot more map" or "slightly more map" in terms of difference between layout/data. As gyoung says, you control the scale of the dataframe in layout just the same as you do in data. There *is* an odd 'glitch' that the scale can change a little when switching, but it can easily be reset to what it was.

Comment: @gyoung1986 Thanks. I did know the scale box allows you to zoom, but I found it more laborious and slower to use than going back and forth from data to layout view. What I didn't know until now is that, on layout view unlike on data view, the magnifying glass and the mouse wheel have different functionalities. On data view, both zoom on the map; on layout, the glass zooms on the map and the wheel on the page to be printed. Using the magnifying glass on layout view should do the trick so I guess I'll continue using this workflow. Thanks you for sharing this!

Comment: @ChrisW I see. So this question was really a duplicate. But I disagree when you say I can control the scale on layout view just the same as I'd do on data view. In speed terms, it doesn't seem the same. On data view, I simply roll the mouse wheel; on layout, the mouse wheel zooms on the page, not on the map, so I thought I had to use that scale box. Because I need to do this many many times, using that box would be a prohibitively slow step in my workflow. Now that gyoung explained I can use the magnifying glass to *quickly* zoom on the map on layout view, this workflow will do for me.

Comment: @ChrisW Precisely what I mean by "more or less map" is: on data view, I zoom in to 1:3,000,000. When I switch to layout view, I get 1:3,297,740, so the generated image contains _a larger portion of the data frame_ (more map?) than the zoomed-in portion I could originally see on data view. It's the 'odd glitch' you mention, what we developers simply call a 'bug', given that this defect is systematically recurrent.

Comment: I can't recall if there is a reason for that glitch, though I've looked into it before. Other developers sometimes refer to them as 'features'. ;) Note if you type a scale in, you can choose it drop-down from that box. I guess that would only help if you're using the same scale each time, and not adjusting to fit. Another method you might look into to speed up your workflow: create a new polygon layer with boxes around all the various areas you need to create separate exports of. Use that layer as the index layer for Data Driven Pages (DDP).

Comment: I would be fired if I delivered a "feature(?)" like this in our software :-) I thought of adding a drop-down index as well, but you've already explained why this is a very(!) bad idea in a workflow such as mine. DDP, on the other hand, sounds like a slightly more promising option, if I realise it's best to always export the exact same areas. I'll keep this suggestion in mind, thanks for that!

Answer (score 2):

ArcGIS has some issues with exporting and transparency:

http://support.esri.com/em/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/32379
http://support.esri.com/cn/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/17336
http://support.esri.com/cn/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/33011

I suspect your issues are related to some of these issues.

Whenever I run into a problem like this it seems like I always end up changing the design of the map to work with the existing ESRI functionality - I rarely find new ways to get ESRI to do what I want.

You might try converting your raster of the compass into a vector, then you will avoid all of the issues ArcMap has with transparency.

Comment: "I rarely find new ways to get ESRI to do what I want" Starting to accept this :) But I really wanted to do something it is supposed to do right? It exports JPEGs or PNGs if the background isn't transparent. I checked the bugs you linked, but it seems this is a different bug: my map is not rotated, the PNG doesn't overlap the layer, nor is the PNG part of a group. Well, because the raster I'm trying to include in the export is a compass and the layout view already has one, I think I'll just deal with the hassle of layout view (described above) and use that compass. Thanks for the links!